# MySQL counting most common value

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a MySQL database where users can list books they've read, want to read etc. I'm trying to write a query to find the most common book that users have listed.

My current query is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title, COUNT(title) AS counttitle FROM books GROUP BY title ORDER BY counttitle DESC LIMIT 1"); 
            echo "<p>The most popular book listed by members is $result</p>";
```

That seems (to me) to be the logical way to do it, and I can't see anything wrong with the syntax, but the result I'm getting is "The most popular book listed by members is Resource id #32"

Anyone any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're missing this:

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
```

The `$result` isn't actually the answer, it's a result resource containing the row that has the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your query is fine, you need to read up on your PHP.

```
 result = mysql_query("SELECT title, COUNT(title) AS counttitle FROM books GROUP BY title ORDER BY counttitle DESC LIMIT 1");
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo "<p>The most popular book listed by members is " . row['title'] . "</p>";
```

Docs: https://www.php.net/mysql_query

> Return Values
>
> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.

Comment: Slight error in syntax there.. it should be $row['title'] in the echo output.

Answer (score 1):

this example should help



`mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");



$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");



while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{


printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);



}`

from here https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array